# Rest-ClickBank sandbox post api not working

Tags: php, rest, curl, clickbank

I am trying to use Sandbox Api of clickBank which accepts a post request.
But somehow it doesnot work.

I am calling clickBank's Prepare Api (https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/prepare) using a POST method.

But it giving me this error
    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2012 12:08:32 GMT Server:     Apache/2.2.22 (FreeBSD) mod_jk/1.2.32 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8q Allow: POST,OPTIONS Content-Length: 1034 Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 1

Here is my code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.2/sandbox/prepare");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml", "Authorization:". $dev_key .":" .$api_key ));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $result;
```

I tried everything but it doesnot seem to work.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before your `curl_exec()`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
```

It worked for me, I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.clickbank.com/rest/1.3/sandbox/prepare");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept:application/json", "Authorization: >>>Your Clickbank Developer API Key from ClickBan->Settings->My Account<<<"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

$return = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```